# Data Grip and and an external file

Tags: datagrip

I have a txt file (id.txt) of 1000 lines; each line is an id.

I'd like to run a query(on dataGrip) of this format SELECT id,title,job FROM table1 WHERE id in id.txt

Thank you

Comment: I guess you mean your `table1` is on some database where you connect using Datagrip? For example on Postgres, you could mount your text file using a _Foreign Data Wrapper_, like [file_fdw](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/file-fdw.html). Then you could `JOIN` the file to your table.

Answer (score 0):

You can import file to a table and make a `JOIN` query.
Like `select id, title, job from table1 join imported_table on table1.id = imported_table.id`